# Why would I want to lock two mutexes in one function - that too with deferred lock?

Tags: c++, std, mutex

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock_tag

```
void transfer(bank_account &from, bank_account &to, int amount)
{
    // lock both mutexes without deadlock
    std::lock(from.m, to.m);
    // make sure both already-locked mutexes are unlocked at the end of scope
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock1(from.m, std::adopt_lock);
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock2(to.m, std::adopt_lock);

// equivalent approach:
//    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock1(from.m, std::defer_lock);
//    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock2(to.m, std::defer_lock);
//    std::lock(lock1, lock2);

    from.balance -= amount;
    to.balance += amount;
}
```

*What do they gain by locking two mutexes at once?

What have they gained by defered lock here?*

Please explain the reason behind that decision of theirs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extension on [Richard Hodges](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2015579/richard-hodges)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51890291/1312382)

> What do they gain by locking two mutexes at once?

Richard explained nicely already, just a little bit more explicit: we avoid dead-lock this way (`std::lock` is implemented such that dead-lock won't occur).

> What have they gained by deferred lock here?

Deferring the lock results in not acquiring it immediately. That's important because if they *did* so, they would just do it without any protection against dead-lock (which the subsequent `std::lock` then achieves).

About dead lock avoidance (see [std::lock](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock)):

> Locks the given Lockable objects lock1, lock2, ..., lockn using a deadlock avoidance algorithm to avoid deadlock.
>
> The objects are locked by an unspecified series of calls to lock, try_lock, and unlock. *[...]*

Side note: another, much simpler algorithm avoiding dead locks is always locking the bank account with e. g. lower account number (AN) first. If a thread is waiting for the lock of higher AN, then the other thread holding it either already has both of the locks acquired or is waiting for the second – which cannot be the one of the first thread as it must have a yet higher AN.

This does not change much for arbitrary number of threads, any thread holding a lower lock is waiting for a higher one, if hold as well. If you draw a directed graph with edges from A to B if A is waiting for second lock that B holds, you'll get a (multi-) tree structure, but you won't ever have circular substructures (which would indicate a dead lock).

Comment: Thanks. This means that std::lock is the only lock which have deadlock avoidance algorithm implemented. std::unique_lock does not have this feature of dead lock avoidance?

Comment: @Aquarius_Girl No, it hasn't. `std::unique_lock` is designed to lock only one single mutex - at *exactly* the time when you either create it (not deferred) or tell it (deferred) by calling `lock` or eventually `try_lock`. Same applies for `std::lock_guard` (apart from not offering deferred locks). This difference gets obvious if you compare the constructors (accepting one single mutex argument) to the function's parameters (multiple lockable objects).

Comment: @Aquarius_Girl And let me yet *explicitly* hint you to the even more basic difference between classes on one side (with destructors unlocking according to RAII principle) and `std::lock` being a function "only" with no unlocking capabilities...

Comment: That is very shocking. I searched Google with "std unlock" but got no relevant results. Am very thankful to you for revealing this. Not sure why an unlock has not been implemented with similar capabilities.

Comment: What is actually done here is combining three tools for different purposes: 1. mutex for thread synchronisation/basic (actual) locking 2. lock_guard/unique_lock for safe unlocking 3. `std::lock` for deadlock safety (avoidance)

Comment: About unlocking: it simply is not necessary. How would you end up in a dead lock on *releasing* a lock? That's not possible... So you can release your locks in arbitrary order as soon as you don't need them any more - which you assure by usage of the guards.

Answer (score 7):

If I modify a bank account without locking it, someone else could try to modify it at the same time. This is a race and the result will be undefined behaviour (usually lost or magically created money).

While transferring money, I am modifying 2 bank accounts. So they both need to be locked.

The problem is that when locking more than one thing, every locker must lock and unlock in the same order, otherwise we get deadlocks.

When it's bank accounts, there is no natural order of locks. Thousands of threads could be transferring money in all directions.

So we need a method of locking more than one mutex in a way that works around this - this is `std::lock`

`std::lock` merely locks the mutex - it does not guarantee unlocking on exit from the current code block.

`std::lock_guard<>` unlocks the mutex it's referring to upon destruction (see RAII). This makes the code behave correctly in all circumstances - even when there is an exception which might cause an early exit from the current code block without the code flowing over statement such as `to.m.unlock()`

A good explanation (with examples) here: https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/cplusplus/CON53-CPP.+Avoid+deadlock+by+locking+in+a+predefined+order

Comment: You could always lock the account with lower (or alternatively higher) account number first, this already would prevent dead locks.

Comment: thanks for the explanation of multiple locks. It would be nice if you could include the use of deferred lock to complete the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The bank account data structure has a lock for each account.

When transferring money from one account to another, we need to lock both accounts (since we are removing money from one and adding it to another). We would like this operation not to deadlock, so lock both at once using `std::lock`, since doing it like that ensures there isn't a deadlock.

After we finish the transaction we need to make sure we release the lock. This code does that using RAII. With the `adopt_lock` tag, we make the object adopt an already locked mutex (which will be released when `lock1` falls out of scope).
With the `defer_lock` tag, we create a `unique_lock` for a currently unlocked mutex, with the intention of locking it later. Again, it will be unlocked when the `unique_lock` falls out of scope.

Answer (score 0):

`from` and `to` are `2` accounts which may be used *anywhere in the application* separatelly.

By having mutex for each account, you make sure *nobody* uses `from` nor `to` accounts while you do the transfer.

`lock_guard` will release mutex when *exiting* from function.