# Why would unlocking two locked bank accounts in a different order result in a deadlock?

Tags: multithreading, thread-safety, mutex, deadlock

https://stackoverflow.com/a/51890291/462608

> If I modify a bank account without locking it, someone else could try to modify it at the same time. This is a race and the result will be undefined behaviour (usually lost or magically created money).
>
> While transferring money, I am modifying 2 bank accounts. So they both need to be locked.
>
> ***The problem is that when locking more than one thing, every locker must lock and unlock in the same order, otherwise we get deadlocks.***

Example: Withdraw from account A and deposit in account B.

So, I would first lock A and then B. Then if I unlock B and then A, why would it result in a deadlock?

Please explain.

Comment: Not trying to be mean, but the very first result for duckduckgo'ing "mutex deadlock" has an example and explanation. I'm sure google or bing or any other search engine would be the same...

Comment: @Shawn I will read what you have pointed towards. I know about deadlocks in producer consumer type problems but not in bank accounts.

Comment: Er, what you're locking with the mutexes doesn't matter. You could use anything as an example. What matters is how you're doing the locking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you can meet the following sequence:

- Thread 1 locks A.
- Thread 2 locks B.
- Thread 1 tries to lock B and blocks.
- Thread 2 tries to lock A and blocks.

Both threads are waiting for each other, so you have a deadlock.

To avoid this you always have to acquire locks in the same order. Unlocking order does not matter.

Comment: I am not sure if there is a duplicate for the question on SO - I failed to fine one, but SO search is PITA to deal with.